# Eclipse Team Synchronizing View: How to remove unversioned items in outgoing changes?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, svnignore

While viewing the outgoing changes in Eclipse Team Synchronization(Subclipse), I am able to see the unversioned files also, like the generated class files, build folders, etc, which I do not want to see in this view. I dont want to add it to svn:ignore, since I have to do it manually for all the additional folders generated.

Is there any setting to change this to show only versioned files in this mode always?
Tortoise SVN client shows this option while committing, to show only versioned files. I am looking for such an option in Subclipse Team Synchronization view. Thanks in advance.

[eclipse_outgoing_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Jov.png)

Answer (score 0):

You **should** svn:ignore build folders.
Otherwise it's only a question of time until you or your colleague checks in the build folder

Answer (score 0):

You should use svn:ignore, and note that once you do for a folder, all child folders are automatically ignored.  In your example, if the build folder were ignored then everything inside it would automatically be ignored.  It looks like your build folder has already been added to repository though, so maybe you can ignore the dist folder inside bin.